# Matplotlib plot image save path python VS Code

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I'm trying to save `matplotlib` barchart plot to `png`. This is my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,5))
data = dataset['hours'].value_counts(ascending=True).nlargest(10)
points = data.values 
total = data.index
ax.barh(total, points)
ax.set_title('Top 10 Restaurant Operational Time') 
ax.set_xlabel('Restaurant') 
ax.set_ylabel('Hours')
fig.savefig('D:\\restovis-scraper\\demo\\static\\images\my_plot.png')
```

It works. But as you can see I must path it specifically. Is there any way I just can path it from `static` folder or at least without `D:`? So if I run my code on another machine, no need to path it specifically. I already tried:

```
fig.savefig('\\static\\images\my_plot.png')
```

But not working. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Removing the starting \\ seems like a solution. Like `fig.savefig('static/images/my_plot.png')`. This should work if you have a `static/images/` directory next to your python file. If this helps I will write a more detailed answer explaining absolute vs. relative path.

Comment: It gave me `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'static/images/my_plot4.png'` error

Comment: Do you have the directory `static/images` next to the python file you run? If you want you can edit your post above to include your project structure (the files and directories(folders) of your project).